# Add a QLineEdit to a qtoolbar in qtcreator (designer)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qwebview

I have trouble with adding controls as a QLineEdit to a QToolbar from the IDE itself not by adding code (I can't do any GUI coding without a WYSIWYG editor)

I'd also like help with overlapping controls on it.

Another last question is how can I get a link from QWebview by hovering it (more like when web browsers show you the link you hover on.

Sorry for asking too much questions i'm a newbie you know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- There are some things you can't do with the Designer, and adding a `QLineEdit` or other widgets to a `QToolBar` is one of them, but you can do it easily with code:

  ```
  ui.toolBar->addWidget(yourLineEdit);
  // or you can place it after an existing action:
  ui.toolBar->insertWidget(ui.anActionInYouToolBar, youLineEdit);
  ```
- `QWebPage` has a signal `linkHovered`.

Comment: just can't seem to find where to put that code VS was much easier with that. and how can i make slots from within the code. thanks for the reply.

Comment: That code goes in the constructor of your window after the call to `ui.setupUi(this);`. But you should really follow [Qt tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/tutorials.html) or read a book about Qt first.

Comment: well thanks for that i thought it went into a form thing like C#